# link.createLink(location, IResource.NONE, null);

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I set a linked folder as described in the link :

https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_linked.htm

But after setting the linked folder, the header Includes path changes and the header files can not be seen, the path of include folder changes to linked folder. And because the linked folder path is same as the beginning of includes path folder, the path names appear to change but header files under includes paths disappear ? Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that *linked Resources* are not the same as a file system's *symbolic links*. The Eclipse Platform maintains its own internal representation of a file system in a component called  *Core Resources*.  Linked Resources they exist solely within Core Resources's representation and are only visible to tools using the Core Resources APIs.

The Core Resources representation usually closely matches the actual file system so most external tools, such as a C compiler, will work fine.  But you will encounter problems when using an Core Resources-only representation such as Linked Resources as that tool will not see those links.